# How do I implement code to get a live update to the displayed UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, ipad, uiimageview

I am trying to figure out how to take a screen capture feed and send it to an iOS device (an iPad in this case) and have the images displayed on the screen, updating as each new image is sent while clearing the old one from memory.

I am just starting with the basics, so I am trying to get the simulator to load a screenshot from the desktop and display it on the screen, and then change the image as I take a new screenshot, and either delete the old one so I can rename the new screenshot to carry the same name or to simply overwrite the old one (thus the reference should still point correctly in the programming code).

I tried using a button that reloaded my UIImageView via:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [UIImageView setImage:ScreenCapture];
}
```

where ScreenCapture is the name of the UIImageView, with the hope that it would reload the existing referenced image.png file, but clicking the button simply exits that program within the simulator and goes back to the simulator's home screen.

Am I using the wrong object when trying to get this done via UIImageView? Is their an existing program/tutorial on this?

I would try to reverse engineer VNC for the iPhone, but both the copyright issues and the amount of advanced programming features are well beyond me.

Once I can get something working through Xcode, I am also planning on trying to implement the same thing via MonoTouch to see which language is easier to use and more beginner friendly.

Thank you for the help,
~Chris

### header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Screen_Capture_3ViewController : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *ScreenCapture;
    IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *Update;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ScreenCapture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *Update;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

### .m:

```
#import "Screen_Capture_3ViewController.h"

@implementation Screen_Capture_3ViewController

@synthesize ScreenCapture;
@synthesize Update;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    [UIImageView setImage:ScreenCapture];
}
```

Everything else remains at the default when selecting "View-based Application", and I connected the ScreenCapture to the UIImageView in Interface builder, as well as Update and buttonPressed to the UIBarButtonItem in Interface Builder.

Comment: Post your code, not just one line.

Comment: Where are you actually getting the image from?

Comment: I'm getting the image from the desktop, using the command-shift-3 screen capture command and renaming every new screen shot to temp.png, overwriting and deleting the previous screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setImage is an instance method, not a class method, so you can't send it directly to UIImageView (nor would it really mean much).

Keep your current code from your question for the header (but only the property should be marked as IBOutlet):

```
@interface Screen_Capture_3ViewController : UIViewController {

UIImageView *ScreenCapture;
UIBarButtonItem *Update;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ScreenCapture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *Update;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender;

@end
```

In your implementation, your event handler should be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIImage* newImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"pathToImage.png"];
    [ScreenCapture setImage:newImage];
}
```

Comment: @lazycs
When I use NSImage, it is not recognized as a "qualifier", like the usage of UIImageView. Is there a special way to implement this type? I used:

IBOutlet NSImage *ScreenCapture2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSImage *ScreenCapture2;
@synthesize ScreenCapture2;

- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
 NSImage *ScreenCapture2 = temp.png
 [ScreenCapture setImage:ScreenCapture2];
}

Comment: Oops I meant UIImage.  I'll update the post.  Also, can you edit your post to show your code on multiple lines?  This is really hard to read.

Comment: It doesn't let me edit comments to be on multiple lines, it uses some form of raw text that places everything on the same line.

Comment: I'll post multiple comments to put it on multiple lines. It is still exiting to the simulator's home screen when trying to use UIImage instead of UIImageView for the buttonPress action. Added code as follows:

Comment: IBOutlet UIImage *ScreenCapture2;

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImage *ScreenCapture2;

Comment: UIImage *ScreenCapture2 = ScreenCapture;

Comment: [ScreenCapture setImage:ScreenCapture2];

Comment: switched to using :::: UIImage *ScreenCapture2 = [UIImage imageNamed: @"temp.png"]; :::: No more crash to home screen, but it is not changing from the image loaded when the program is compiled and initiated even when that image is deleted from the desktop and replaced

Comment: See my revised answer.  It will only work if the png file on the iPad is replaced somehow.  Just changing the file on the desktop of your computer won't update the image on the iPad.  You need networking code for that.

Comment: I tried implementing the code exactly as you have written, but it immediately crashes to the simulator home screen. Do I need to declare newImage somewhere to prevent this?

Comment: If I use imageNamed instead of imageWithContentsOfFile it seems to function without crashing. However, as you said, I cannot update the image on the simulator through an image on the desktop without exiting and restarting the simulator. I guess I need to start looking into ways to simulate a couple network addresses between the simulator and the desktop and figure out how to get them to communicate. Thanks for the help!